# Getting weird character in git terminal of vs-code

Tags: git

Getting weird characters in the git terminal of vs-code. Anyone how to resolve this problem. Well, I'm not having a problem running my code but it doesn't look good. If anyone how to resolve this is really helpful. Well, I've already had the latest version of git.
**I'm talking about these characters**

```
←[36m ←[0m
```

[image]

Comment: I am seeing this too, in all my terminal windows inside VS Code (but not outside of it):

cmd, 
python, 
R interactive, 
bash, 
etc.   

Stuff like this:
"
Examples from AI knowledge base:
←[96mhttps://aka.ms/cli_ref←[0m
←[90mRead more about the command in reference docs←[0m
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're simply [ASCII Escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Nothing to worry about.

If they really annoy you, you might try installing this VSCode plugin:

- ANSI Colors: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iliazeus.vscode-ansi

ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION:

Go into Terminal > Settings (`@feature:terminal`) and make sure the terminalis "Integrated terminal". Update your post if it's "something else".

Comment: Do I need to do anything else after installing it. Because I've installed it but doesn't work

Comment: These "escape characters" go back to the days when programmers used vt100 CRT terminals.  Linux terminals, DOS command prompts and putty ssh sessions - among many other apps - still support them.  That's what you're seeing.  Since "ANSI colors" was designed specifically to support them, I was hoping it might help.  Perhaps you can configure your VSCode Git client to not use escape codes.  Perhaps you can configure whatever terminal the VSCode Git client uses to handle them (e.g. put the terminal into "vt100 mode", or equivalent)  Personally, I would just ignore them :)

Comment: how can I configure the VSCode Git client to not use escape codes?

Comment: as you said I'm also ignoring this problem now because I can resolve it also nothing I get from online resources it's like no one face such a problem, or If they faced they ignore such problem

Comment: I installed the plugin and also added `TERM=cygwin` to `.bashrc` and I still don't see the colours in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `TERM=cygwin` to the `.bashrc` file worked for me. You'll need to restart the terminal for it to take effect.